# CustomTableViewCell with xib. I can't wire up the labels to the custom state table cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've just created `CustomTableViewCell.xib`. Then I created class `CustomTableViewCell` with `IBOutlets`. In the identity inspector I changed the type to my `CustomTableViewCell`.

```
 @interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
{
IBOutlet NSString *placeName;
IBOutlet NSString *address;
IBOutlet NSString *distance;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *placeName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *address;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *distance;

@end
```

But I can't wire up the labels to the custom state table cell. Please see the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need to use:

```
IBOutlet UILabel * placeNameLabel
...
```

instead. Then, set the text in the label view.